# How to get the latest file postfix name c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two files in my directory, I have created an array and each of them have an unique postfix. In this array, there are two files. I want to the program to select the latest file 20160906. If there are 3rd file (20170906) then I want to program to select this filename. Help would be appreciated.

```
myArray: 
[0] = myFile20150906
[1] = myFile20160906
[2] = myFile20170906
```

expected Result:

```
string latestFile = 'myFile20170906'
```

Comment: is `myArray` an array of strings?

Comment: yes, It is a string

Comment: `string latestFile = myArray.ToList<string>().OrderByDescending(x=>x).FirstOrDefault();`?

Comment: How about `string latest = myArray.Max();` (no need to sort it if you just want the max)

Comment: what about  `string latest = myArray[myArray.Length-1];`

Comment: @MatthewWatson. That's the best way

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter that would only work if the array is filled in order

Comment: I would use a tiny private inner class that wraps the file name and has a property "IsValid" (to filter out everything that does not end with 8 digits, add additional checks if needed), and a property that returns the date as datetime. Then use a Linq expression like: (from e in myFiles select new PrivateFileInfo(e)).Where(x => x.IsValid).OrderByDescending(x => x.EditDate).FirstOrDefault()?.FileName;

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. @MatthewWatson, isn't .Max() method is just for integer not string?

Comment: @RedRocket No, `Max()` works for any type that implements `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>`

Comment: @RedRocket Ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your strings are all in the format `myFileYYYYMMDD` then comparing them as strings will be the same as comparing them in date order.

Because of this, you can use [`Enumerable.Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the latest date, like so:

```
string latest = myArray.Max();
```

Note that `Enumerable.Max()` works with any type that implements `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>`, which includes `string`.